# Deleting Empty Lists from Output

Tags: python, windows

The following code goes through all sub-directories that start with "F3E3" and then retrieves all csv files that include "0.1Hz" in the filename. I then sort those csv files by the last created csv file.

```
    directory = r"\DATA"
    subdirs = [os.path.join(directory, fl) for fl in os.listdir(directory) if fl.startswith("F3E3")]
    for subdir in subdirs:
        filenames = [os.path.join(subdir, fl) for fl in os.listdir(subdir) if fl.endswith(".csv") and ("0.1Hz" in fl)]
        result = [x for x in filenames if x != []]
        final_list = sorted(result, key=os.path.getctime, reverse=True)
        print (final_list)
```

The problem is that some of the sub-directories that start with "F3E3" do not contain any csv files that have "0.1Hz" in the filename. So, the code is outputting:

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
['\DATA\\F3E31\\F3E31TEST_0.1Hz_2017-01-28.csv','\DATA\\F3E31\\F3E31TEST_0.1Hz_2017-01-27.csv']
['\DATA\\F3E317\\F3E317_TEST_0.1Hz_2017-02-18.csv', '\DATA\\F3E317\\F3E317_TEST_0.1Hz_2017-02-17.csv']
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

How do I get rid of these empty lists in the output? I am not sure why **result = [x for x in filenames if x != []]** is not taking care of this problem.

Comment: It would be easier for us and for you if you didn't use oneliners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the elements in `filenames` are not lists, they are strings. Hence, `x != []` will always pass. So the loop that prepares `result` really does not do anything. You're gonna have to use an if statement instead, something like

```
if len(filenames) > 0:
    final_list = sorted(result, key=os.path.getctime, reverse=True)
```

or

```
if len(filenames) == 0: continue
```

in place of the `result` line.

You should add a print statement on the `filenames` variable to check if it indeed contains lists or strings.

Comment: Works great. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to have helped! Hope you don't mind upvoting and marking it as the accepted solution :)